# How to create a method that returns the ceiling

Tags: java

How to use a method that returns the ceiling of a double without using the java method Math.ceil()? I have gotten this far, but I don't understand how to create the code to round to the next largest number of say 2.2 = 3

public static double ceiling(double num)
    {
        return num;
    }

Comment: You haven't tried to solve this problem. You seem to just be returning the number given.

Comment: Of course, Stack Overflow is probably going to close this as being too broad / no research / no real attempt to solve / homework.

Comment: I see that your question was migrated, but the format on this forum requires you to make an effort, show code, and then state a specific problem.  You've just asked for an answer without any apparent attempt to try.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    double x = 2.0;
    double temp = Math.round(x + 0.5);
    if(temp - x == 1) {
        temp = Math.round(x);
    }
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Comment: This does not work in border cases, e.g. for x=2 you get 3 while the correct result is 2.

Comment: This is still wrong.  Due to finite precision, you cannot be sure that these operations will always give what you want.

Comment: @Brick my feeling is that this is not an issue here. Integers and numbers 1/2 higher than an integer can be represented exactly as a double (unless the absolute value is too high; but then also the other proposed methods break down)

Comment: @Henry Interesting point, but even so, you get a round-off error from addition in general.  Are you ensured in this case that the error is actually zero?

Comment: @Brick on closer analysis, you are right. adding 1/2 can only lead to rounding error if the integer part of the results needs one more bit in the binary representation. For example 1.5 <= x < 2. The interesting case here are numbers close to but less than 2. Adding 0.5 can lead to a result of exactly 2.5 due to rounding, which will then again be rounded to temp = 3. temp - x is then  > 1 and we get indeed a wrong result. This could be fixed by making the test `temp - x >= 1`.

Comment: @Brick a numeric example where we get a wrong result is 2 - Math.pow(2, -52).

Answer (score 0):

Check if number is more than its `floor`.

If yes, return its `floor` plus 1 to reach the `ceil`.

Otherwise, return its floor, which will be the `int` version of the number.

```
private int ceil(double num) {
    int floor = (int) num;
    return num > floor ? floor + 1 : floor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public static double ceiling(double num) { 
        int c = (int) num; 
        return (c==num) ? c : c + 1; 
    }
```